# ChoiceField no muestra valores cuando es None

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de contar las personas por raza y me cuenta correcto excepto los que son `NULL`:

```
RAZA_CHOICES = (
('raizal', _('Raizal')),
('afro', _('Afro')),
('indigena', _('Indigena')),
('blanco', _('Blanco')),
('mestizo', _('Mestizo')))

class PersonaBase:
    # Otros atributos
    raza = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,
                            choices=RAZA_CHOICES,
                            verbose_name=_("Autoreconocimento étnico"))

class Simpatizante(TimeStampedModel, PersonaBase):
    # Otros atributos
```

Esta el la sentencia que uso para hacer el conteo:

```
num_simpatizates_raza_qs = Simpatizante.objects.values('raza')\
    .annotate(num_simpatizantes_raza=Count('raza'))\
    .order_by('-raza')
```

Así es como me esta regresando la información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que te falta introducir en que lenguaje o framework es, en si mas detalles , y no se si estas compartiendo o preguntando. Mejora la redacción y detalles para poder ayudarte

Comment: la solucion , es agregar a tu `RAZA_CHOICES ` un elemento para los nulos algo como `RAZA_CHOICES = (
('', 'Sin Informacion'),
('raizal', _('Raizal')),
('afro', _('Afro')),
('indigena', _('Indigena')),
('blanco', _('Blanco')),
('mestizo', _('Mestizo'))),`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos formas para hacerlo:

**Opcion 1:**
Agregar el campo `''` a tu lista :

```
RAZA_CHOICES = (
('', 'Sin Informacion'),
('raizal', _('Raizal')),
('afro', _('Afro')),
('indigena', _('Indigena')),
('blanco', _('Blanco')),
('mestizo', _('Mestizo')))

class PersonaBase:
    # Otros atributos
    raza = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,
                            choices=RAZA_CHOICES,
                            verbose_name=_("Autoreconocimento étnico"))
```

Opcion 2: Importa y usar [BLANK_CHOICE_DASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/)

```
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
RAZA_CHOICES = (
('raizal', _('Raizal')),
('afro', _('Afro')),
('indigena', _('Indigena')),
('blanco', _('Blanco')),
('mestizo', _('Mestizo')))

class PersonaBase:
    # Otros atributos
    raza = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,
                            choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + list(RAZA_CHOICES),
                            verbose_name=_("Autoreconocimento étnico"))
```

Comment: Use ambas formas, pero ninguna funciono, sigue sin contar los registros `null`

Comment: agregas registros de base datos para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: probe la primera opcion y me funciona, tienes datos en null y blancos?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con datos que ya existen, varios de los registros tienen el campo `raza` como `NULL`